# ffprobe output never show flag that represents loop info

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Since i need to get a GIF file's "is loop" and "how many?" with ffprobe.
I watched all official documentations and tips but still cannot found what i want.

Is there some param like this ?

```bsh
ffprobe -show_loop -i FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the git branch as of now, this info has been added as a debug log.

Run

```
ffmpeg -i in.gif -v debug 2>&1 | grep "Loop"
```

If the GIF has a Netscape loop block or similar,

the above command will print a line of the form

```
Loop count is X
```

X=0 represents infinite looping.

Comment: That working for me. After i git cloned package file and Maked, ffmpeg returned what i want. Thanks good work and is this feature contained in latest version?

Comment: It will be in the first release series after 4.4